# Resizing a JPanel and its components to show hidden elements

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, layout-manager

I've a class that extends `JPanel` I use it as GUI to hold a worker information including a salary which is available in two options chosen by radio buttons.

When **the first one** is chosen **nothing has to be done on the panel.**

But if the **second radio button is chosen** we have to show some extra text fields, and *here comes the problem - my panel does not resize to fit the components and its goes totally in disorder.

I've tried to implement an observer pattern but it doesn't work or may have done it wrong
here in follow the main parts of my class.

```
public class EmpDetails extends JPanel {

public EmpDetails() {

    matriculeLab = new JLabel("MATRICULE :");
    matriculeTxt = new JTextField(10);


    nomLab = new JLabel("Nom :");
    nomTxt = new JTextField(30);


    serviceLab = new JLabel("SERVICE :");
    serviceDrBx = new JComboBox<>();

    fonctionLab = new JLabel("FONCTION :");
    fonctionDrBx = new JComboBox<>();


    dateEmbLab = new JLabel("DATE D'EMBAUCHE :");
    dateEmb = DatePick.getDatePick();

    ///  This is the first radio button 

    salaireFxBtn = new JRadioButton("FIXE ");
    salaireFxBtn.setSelected(true);


    /// This is the second radio button that shows the hiden elements 

    salaireChngBtn = new JRadioButton("CHANGEANT ");


    bg.add(salaireFxBtn);
    bg.add(salaireChngBtn);

    btnPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    btnPanel.add(salaireFxBtn);
    btnPanel.add(salaireChngBtn);


    salaireLab = new JLabel("MONTANT DU SALAIRE:");
    montatSalFix = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance());


    /// This is the panel holding the hidden elements its shown when radio button 2 is clicked

    salPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));

    salaire1 = new JLabel("MONTANT SALAIRE 1:");
    montantSal1 = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance());

    salPanel.add(salaire1);
    salPanel.add(montantSal1);

    periodeLab1 = new JLabel("DUREE 1 :");
    periode1 = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance());

    salPanel.add(periodeLab1);
    salPanel.add(periode1);

    salaire2 = new JLabel("MONTANT SALAIRE 2:");
    montantSal2 = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance());

    salPanel.add(salaire2);
    salPanel.add(montantSal2);

    periodeLab2 = new JLabel("DUREE 2 :");
    periode2 = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance());

    salPanel.add(periodeLab2);
    salPanel.add(periode2);

    salaire3 = new JLabel("MONTANT SALAIRE 3:");
    montantSal3 = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance());

    salPanel.add(salaire3);
    salPanel.add(montantSal3);

    periodeLab3 = new JLabel("DUREE 3 :");
    periode3 = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance());

    salPanel.add(periodeLab3);
    salPanel.add(periode3);

    salPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY, 1));
    salPanel.setVisible(false);

    indemLab = new JLabel("INDEMNITE :");
    indemnite = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance());



    salaireChngBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if (salaireChngBtn.isSelected()) {
                salPanel.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });

    salaireFxBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if (salaireFxBtn.isSelected()) {
                salPanel.setVisible(false);
            }

        }
    });

    layoutComponents();
    setVisible(true);
}

private void layoutComponents() {
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gb = new GridBagConstraints();

    //   The rest is an implementation of the GridBagLayout to design the interface
    }
}
```

***Here is the Layout***

```
private void layoutComponents() {
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gb = new GridBagConstraints();

    gb.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    gb.weightx = 1;
    gb.weighty = 1;
    gb.insets = new Insets(7, 7, 7, 7);

    // LINE 01 //
    gb.gridx = 0;
    gb.gridy = 0;

    add(matriculeLab, gb);
    gb.gridx++;
    add(matriculeTxt, gb);

    gb.gridx++;
    add(nomLab, gb);
    gb.gridx++;
    add(nomTxt, gb);

    // LINE 02 //
    gb.gridx = 0;
    gb.gridy = 1;

    add(serviceLab, gb);
    gb.gridx++;
    add(serviceDrBx, gb);

    gb.gridx++;
    add(fonctionLab, gb);
    gb.gridx++;
    add(fonctionDrBx, gb);

    // LINE 03 //
    gb.gridx = 0;
    gb.gridy++;

    add(dateEmbLab, gb);
    gb.gridx++;
    add(dateEmb, gb);

    // LINE 04 //
    gb.gridx = 0;
    gb.gridy++;

    add(btnPanel, gb);

    // LINE 05 //
    gb.gridx = 0;
    gb.gridy++;

    add(salaireLab, gb);
    gb.gridx++;
    add(montatSalFix, gb);



    // LINE 0 //
    gb.gridx = 0;
    gb.gridy++;

    add(salPanel, gb);

    // LINE 09 //
    gb.gridx = 0;
    gb.gridy++;

    add(indemLab, gb);
    gb.gridx++;
    add(indemnite, gb);
}
```

Comment: Without the layout logic, it's going to be impossible to provide any real advice...

Comment: "_if [a] button is chosen…show some extra textfields_" suggests having a look at [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've added the layout if you could give more help

Comment: @trashgod I'll have a look on it, thnks

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue using ***CardLayout***
I created a JPanel for the CardLayout it self and two other JPanels for each type of the salary
I used two **action listeners** on each radio button to switch to the next card